# How to get Jquery cycle to correctly fade separate div's, one on top of the other

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

had a look through other posts and couldn't find any (with answers at least) that fit my problem. Which is:

I have a group of images that I am using jquery cycle to fade in and out on a loop. Works great! But what I want to do is have another div (which is a caption talking about the image) floating on top. This 'caption' div would also fade with each image so that the appropriate caption displays with each image.

I could of course, just make the caption part of the image, but I was hoping to retain the ease of editing that the HTML provides.

I have managed to get the slideshow operating on both the image and the caption div's but the problem is that the image keeps appearing on top of the caption, effectively hiding the caption (I can see the caption transitioning underneath when the image is semi-transparent during its fade to the next image).

So, does anyone know how to get the caption to appear on top? (by the way, if I don't have the slideshow running on the caption it successfully stays on top of the images transitioning. Unfortunately the caption doesn't change this way!).

Any help you can offer (even if it's a different pluggin) would be appreciated!

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search gave me this:

http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/

May not exactly be what you're looking for, but it looks fairly customizable.

Comment: Thanks heaps Bryan! It looks like it could be a winner. Having a look at some of the code has also given me ideas of how I could be doing it better with cycle too, so I might try that too.